# Proper way to update node_modules in a shared git repository

Tags: git, npm

Ok so I work on a project with friends (we're all beginners...) and I wonder:

If I update the node_modules (update, update -save-dev), I change the package.json and the package-lock.json, changes that will be reflected on the remote repository once committed and pushed.
But since the node_modules are in .gitignore, the next pull my friends will update their config files but not their node_modules directory, isn't it?
What's the proper way to do that? each one update independently, one update and the other "rm -rf" their node_modules and install, not caring about it...

Comment: They should just run `npm install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the whole point of excluding the `node_modules` directory using your .gitignore file — You don't mistakenly mess up each others files. The `package.json` file handles it all.

Others should just run `npm install` and update their dependencies whenever anything is added to the `package.json` file.